# Connection with database from raspberry pi

Tags: php, mysql, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to echo or print content from a database in my terminal on my raspberry pi. I installed MySql client and PHP5. I want to run a php file in my terminal so i created a file:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("mysql51-025.wc1","username","password","dbname")
//first one is hostname

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "failed to connect with error: ". mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

When i run this in my terminal on my raspberrypi

> pi@raspberrypi ~ $ php database.php

I'll get this returned:

> PHP warning: mysqli_connect(): (hy000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host
>   'nameofmyhostinphpfile' (25) in /home/pi/database.php on line 8 
>   failed to connect with error: Unknown MySql server host 'hostname'

My question is how i can make this connection work. And will i be able to execute queries and echo or print those results on my pi and use those results in shell scripts?

Thank you!

Comment: This name could only be resolved in a local network or with the help of a host file. If you want to query a mysql server installed on your raspberry pi then use `localhost` instead.

Comment: The server is not on my pi, so i want to connect an external one, how can i do this?

Comment: Make sure you have a user who's allowed access from remote. And use either the IP address of the remote server or create an entry in `/etc/hosts` so your raspberry pi can resolve the hostname of your mysql server.

Comment: I should be allowed to access from remote cause i've done it manually on different devices. I don't have the IP address so i should create an entry, how do i do this exactly? thanks btw!

Comment: Have you access to one of those devices?

Comment: I have to say no. I can access them, but i dont want to have connection with them from my pi. My pi should read data from an external database and read them (text to speech) through a audiobox. So a user is going to press a button, the pi reacts by reading database content.

Comment: What I would rather ask: can execute a query on this mysql server? If yes, then there's a way to get the IP address of the mysql server.

Comment: On the pi, if you do `nslookup mysql51-025.wc1`, does it resolve?